# Checkbox list to a new line

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

[image]

I want to move the list of my choices in the checkbox to a new line without exceeding 100% of the form.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <legend class="form-label">Votre profession<i class="note-form">*</i></legend>
            <div class="form-check-inline" id="profession_emprunteur">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_0" name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio" value="employe"/>
                    <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special" for="profession_emprunteur_0">Employé</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_1" name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio" value="fonctionnaire"/>
                    <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special" for="profession_emprunteur_1">Fonctionnaire</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_2" name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio" value="cadre"/>
                    <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special" for="profession_emprunteur_2">Cadre</label>
                </div>
                
                
                .....
                
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thenk's

Comment: share your HTML and CSS code that you have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the display to the element of id `profession_emprunteur` and add the property `float:left` to the choices, so they will be displayed beside each other, but when the line is full the next ones will be displayed on the next line etc.

```html
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .form-lite {
            -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            -ms-border-radius: 2px;
            -o-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
            background-color: #fcfcfc;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #979797;
            margin-top: 50px;
            padding: 50px 50px 30px 50px;
            color: #1b1e21;
        }

        .note-form {
            color: #e37d5a;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        .radio-special {
            visibility: hidden;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
        }

        .radio-special:active + label,
        .radio-special:checked + label {
            background-color: #292780;
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        .form-label {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 18px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            color: #292780;
        }

        .label-special {
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #292780;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            margin-right: 0;
            margin-left: 5px;
            border: solid 1px #292780;
            border-radius: 3px;

            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .label-special:hover {
            background-color: #4ba0e5;
            color: #fff;
            border: solid 1px #4b92e4;
        }
        
        .form-check-inline#profession_emprunteur {
            display: inherit;
        }
        
        .form-check-inline#profession_emprunteur .form-check {
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: 0.2em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<main class="main-content">
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
                    <form class="form-lite input-round" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <legend class="form-label">Votre profession<i class="note-form">*</i></legend>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline" id="profession_emprunteur">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_0"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="employe"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_0">Employé</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_1"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="fonctionnaire"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_1">Fonctionnaire</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_2"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="cadre"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_2">Cadre</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_3"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="retraite"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_3">Retraité</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_4"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="profession-liberale"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_4">Profession libérale</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_5"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="enseignant"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_5">Enseignant</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_6"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="artisan"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_6">Artisan</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_7"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="commercant"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_7">Commerçant</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_8"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="chef-entreprise"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_8">Chef d&#039;entreprise</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_9"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="etudiant"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_9">Etudiant</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_10"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="agriculteur"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_10">Agriculteur</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's better don't use float for layout purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .form-lite {
            -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
            -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            -ms-border-radius: 2px;
            -o-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
            background-color: #fcfcfc;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #979797;
            margin-top: 50px;
            padding: 50px 50px 30px 50px;
            color: #1b1e21;
        }

        .note-form {
            color: #e37d5a;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        .radio-special {
            visibility: hidden;
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
        }

        .radio-special:active + label,
        .radio-special:checked + label {
            background-color: #292780;
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

        .form-label {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 18px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            color: #292780;
        }

        .label-special {
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #292780;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            margin-right: 0;
            margin-left: 5px;
            border: solid 1px #292780;
            border-radius: 3px;

            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .label-special:hover {
            background-color: #4ba0e5;
            color: #fff;
            border: solid 1px #4b92e4;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<main class="main-content">
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
                    <form class="form-lite input-round" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <legend class="form-label">Votre profession<i class="note-form">*</i></legend>
                                    <div class="form-check-inline" id="profession_emprunteur">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_0"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="employe"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_0">Employé</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_1"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="fonctionnaire"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_1">Fonctionnaire</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_2"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="cadre"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_2">Cadre</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_3"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="retraite"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_3">Retraité</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_4"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="profession-liberale"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_4">Profession libérale</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_5"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="enseignant"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_5">Enseignant</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_6"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="artisan"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_6">Artisan</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_7"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="commercant"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_7">Commerçant</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_8"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="chef-entreprise"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_8">Chef d&#039;entreprise</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_9"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="etudiant"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_9">Etudiant</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input class="radio-special form-check-input" id="profession_emprunteur_10"
                                                   name="profession_emprunteur" required="required" type="radio"
                                                   value="agriculteur"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label required font-normal label-special"
                                                   for="profession_emprunteur_10">Agriculteur</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```